# "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device" even though I've 100 GB+ of Space left in it

Tags: python, pip, installation

**Environment**
pip version: 20.1.1
Python version: 3.7.7
OS: Windows 10

Newly Created Virtual Environment 'face',

Package Version

numpy 1.18.5
pip 20.1.1
setuptools 41.2.0

**Description**
The Local Drive in which I'm trying to install the package 'deepface' has 100+ GB of free storage left. But, still my error of 'No Space left on Device' is persisting. [Error Code attached Below]

**Expected behavior**
I was expecting to install 'deepface' safely and successfully in my virtual environment and do my work.

**How to Reproduce**
Create a Virtual Environment, and pip install deepface and this error which come up even if I've plenty of space left.

**Output**

```
(face) D:\Work\Face Recognition>pip install deepface
Collecting deepface
Using cached deepface-0.0.24-py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Collecting tqdm>=4.30.0
Downloading tqdm-4.46.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
|████████████████████████████████| 63 kB 416 kB/s
Collecting gdown>=3.10.1
Using cached gdown-3.11.0.tar.gz (8.6 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting Flask>=1.1.2
  Using cached Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting opencv-python>=3.4.4
  Downloading opencv_python-4.2.0.34-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (33.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 33.1 MB 99 kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.0 in d:\work\face recognition\face\lib\site-packages (from deepface) (1.18.5)
Collecting tensorflow>=1.9.0
  Downloading tensorflow-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (459.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 459.2 MB 72 kB/s
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Can sort of Help would be very beneficial. Here's my overview of my computer storage. Though I acknowledge that I've very less space in C Drive, but I was performing the installation in D Drive using Virtual Environment.
[Space Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaxP4.png)

Comment: `No space left on device" even though I've 100 GB+ of Space left in it` any proof? 'cos apparently your machine thinks differently about free space **on disk it wanna use**.

Comment: I suspect your Local Drive is different from the system drive (where `C:\Windows` resides) and the problem could be with free space at `C:`.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski  ```Caption  FreeSpace     Size
C:       2771554304    125867581440
D:       145676341248  920026869760
E:       1494155264    14735634432
Z:       819892224     18253606912 ```

Answer (score 3):

Although you run `pip install` in a virtual environment, it downloads and [cache](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#caching) the wheel file into default folder which is `<CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA>\pip\Cache` in windows. In your case this folder is located in `C` partition, When you install a new library whether in a virtual environment or globally, first it downloads into the cache folder then pip uses that downloaded wheel file for further `pip install` commands.

try cleaning space in `c` partition.

Comment: I did. Even tried the same with specifying a different temp folder and also by using no cache. And yes, I even tried freeing up space from my C Drive. None is working fine.

Comment: sine deepface requires some large libraries such as tensorflow, there should be at least 1.5GB free space. did you free that much amount?

Comment: Yes, Currently I've 2.59 GB of clear space in C. I think that would be enough for DeepFace. But ain't working, same error popping up again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I face the similar error in Ubuntu 18.04. After **upgrade pip** and then change the pip cache directory, it worked.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
export PIP_CACHE_DIR=/new_dir/
```