# How do I get my VM to pip install dependencies on my attached disk?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pip, virtual-machine, disk, disk-partitioning

I needed to pip install openai-whisper to my google cloud VM for a project but I got the error

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

so I attached a new standart persistent disk (sda) with 20Gb. It wasn't mounted when I attached it, ignore the "/mnt/disks/mymountdir":

[image]

I am new to working on SSH so I looked up a lot of tutorials but this one got me the furthest: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sT7-_qn71cw. The tutorial's attached disk was named "sdb", mine was "sda" so our commands are minutely different. Here is what I did to mount:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard /dev/sda
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/disks/mymountdir
sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sda /mnt/disks/mymountdir
sudo chmod a+w /mnt/disks/mymountdir
```

Then I tried installing again but got the same error. When checked with "df -hT" I saw that the new disk was barely used.
[image]

I also tried using --target with a smaller package (numpy) but here is what I got:

[image]

So I tried again with "**sudo** pip install --target=/mnt/disks/mymount/dir numpy" which installed *somewhere* but the attached disk was still empty.

**VM**

Machine type: n1-standard-1

CPU platform: Intel Haswell

Minimum CPU platform: None

Architecture: x86/64

**PS.** I know that running whisper on cpu isn't a good idea. I am testing on my cpu-only vm to avoid getting billed too much as I figure it out. I got the same problem on my other VMs with GPUs.

**Update:** I used "sudo chown -R $USER /mnt/disks/mymountdir" and I no longer get permission issues when I use --target without "sudo". I was able to install numpy and see that the new disk had been used. However, when I tried installing openai-whisper, I got:
[image]
It does the same thing when I try to install torch separately.

Comment: Use df -h to find the available disk space:



As stated [here,](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5816#issuecomment-425205365) you can perform the following command to install it by creating a directory where you have adequate space, such as /folder/address/here/.

To install the package, use the following command and specify the --cache-dir as well:

**TMPDIR=/folder/address/here/ pip install --cache-dir=$TMPDIR --build $TMPDIR package-name**

Comment: Make sure that you have the necessary permissions to install packages on the mounted disk. You can try using the sudo command to elevate your privileges. Also ensure that you have the latest version of pip installed.

Comment: @ Positive Have you checked my comments

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu thank you so much for the answer. I am in a meeting right now, but I will try it as soon as possible in ~1-2 hours.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40757314/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/71316448/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22No+space+left+on+device%22

Comment: @ Positive You can find more resources on how to resolve this kind of issue by searching for "linux /tmp." "[No space left on the device](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/having-problem-with-tmp-no-space-left-on-device-error-727905/)" for example.

Comment: @Positive Refer to this copyprogramming [blog](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/could-not-install-due-to-environment-error) helps to resolve your issue

Comment: @ Positive Have you checked my comments